# Vue, checkbox and computed properies

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a Vue 2 application and, in a page, I need to keep track of the value of a single checkbox. So I did this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            v-model="checkboxValue"
            /> Check to accept payment <a href="url" target="_blank">terms and conditions</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        cardData: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
        eventBus: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
        url: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            checkboxValue: false,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        forwardCheckboxValue() {
            console.log(this.checkboxValue);
            this.eventBus.$emit("checkbox_value", {
                checkboxValue: this.checkboxValue,
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Basically I want to keep track if the checkbox is selected or not, and everytime the value changes I want to emit an event that warns me about that.

The problem is that the console.log in the computed property is not triggered.
What am I missing?

Comment: I think you actually want a watcher and not a computed property here. However you could test your computed prop by actually returning the value outputting it on the ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) and remove `checkboxValue` from the `data` option. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/aaa43joy/1/)

```
computed:{
    checkboxValue:{
        get(){
            return false;
        },
        set(newValue){
            this.$emit('checkbox-changed', newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Or as **frank provost** suggested set up a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) which should have the same name of the `data` property you are watching. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/aaa43joy/2/)

```
watch:{
    checkboxValue(newValue){
        this.$emit('checkbox-changed', newValue);
    }
}
```